# How can I prevent a link from loading the whole webpage in a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird issue. My webpage has about 50 headlines from 10 or 12 different websites. When a user clicks on any one of the headlines (which is a link to the actual article), the webpage is supposed to only show the main content of that article in the modal window. It works every time except during the first click. Here is a screenshot of the network tab with XHR requests.

[image]

As you can see, the first link that I click on loads an extra XHR request. This behavior is not specific to any one website. The first click on any of the headlines results in two requests. By first click, I don't mean the first time a user clicks an individual headline. I mean the overall first click on any of the headlines.

In the screenshot above, I first clicked on the third headline which loaded AJAX request as well as the actual link. Then I click on the first headline and it did not result in any extra XHR request. To make sure that it is not something specific to a website, I clicked on the third headline again. This time, there was not extra XHR request. I have used `e.preventDefault()` and it prevents the loading of extra request only after the first click.

Here is my code:

```
$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);
```

This is my openModal function:

```
function openModal(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
  var page = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  var text = $(this).text();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/getarticle.php",
    data: {
      link: link,
      page: page
    },
    success: function(markup) {
      $(".feed-modal .modal-body").html(markup);
    }
})
```

Comment: you should provide the rest of `openModal`. You might not see an AJAX request if the page is cached.

Comment: I have never written things like this before. Usually I pass an anonymous function as the second parameter like ```function( evt ) { /* your code */ }```

Comment: @pcnate I am sorry if the code is messy. Is this the wrong way of doing things? I am a beginner.

Comment: @cambunctious I am adding the complete code.

Comment: As a first debugging step, I would put a `console.log(link, page, text)` and/or a `debugger;` into that function to  find out what is happening when.

Comment: @sebastian_k I have already done that. There is nothing unexpected there.

Comment: If it was an issue like that I suppose it would have happened every time I click on a link.

Comment: Ah, wait – see how the second AJAX request wasn't initiated by you, but by that 9to5 website? When you open that website, it itself makes XHRs to load extra content – nothing you can do about that, I'm afraid.

Now, you say this is independent of the website you click on. Is it really? Is it always the same XHR that gets sent the first time, with the same initiator? Or is it maybe that *most* websites make their own XHRs, but for some reason only the first one after opening the new modal ends up in your inspector window?

Comment: @pcnate so you are a beginner, too?

Comment: @sebastian_k Sorry, I missed your comment. "most websites make their own XHRs, but for some reason only the first one after opening the new modal ends up in your inspector window". You are right about it.  My question is if something is preventing the rest of XHR requests from executing, I should be able to prevent the first one too.